# Expression $f$ on $\mathbb{T^n}$ in terms of $\hat{f}$.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm studying Real analysis, Folland section 8.4 page 257. I can't undersfand the below highlighted statement.

If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T^n})$ and $\hat{f}$ $\in l^1(\mathbb{Z^n})$, then the Fourier series $\sum_k \hat{f}(x)e^{2\pi ik\cdot x}$ converges absolutely and uniformly to a function $g$. Since $l^1 \subset l^2$, **it follows from Theorem 8.20 ($e^{2\pi ik\cdot x}$'s consist an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{T^n})$) that $f \in L^2$ and that the series converges to $f$ in the $L^2$ norm.**

From Theorem 8.20, I confirm that $g$ is in $L^2$. But, why $f$ should be in $L^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hat{f}$ $\in l^1(\mathbb{Z^n})$ implies that $\hat{f}$ $\in l^2(\mathbb{Z^n})$ and this implies that the Fourier series converges in $L^2$ to $f$. Since it converges pointiwse to $g$ it follows that $f=g$ a.e..

[If the FS converges to $F$ then $F$ and $f$ are $L^{1}$ functions  having the same Fourier coefficients, which implies that $F=f$ a.e. Hence the series converges to $f$ in $L^{2}$].

Comment: I can't catch that the Fourier series converges to $f$. I just know this series converges some function in $L^2$, but why it must be $f$?

Comment: Before we confirm converging to $f$ in $L^2$ sense, shouldn't we check that $f$ is in $L^2$?

Comment: It follows by uniqueness of Fourier coefficients of $L^{1}$ functions. If the series converges to $F$ then you can easily see that $f$ and $F$ have the same Fourier coefficients, so $F=f$. a.e.  @HanJeong

Comment: I don't know if it's a good example, but the function kind of $e^{-1/x}$ has the Taylor series, and the Taylor series has the unique coefficient. But the series does not converge to the given function, but zero function.

Comment: That is a totally different situation. How does it contradict the proof I gavee in above comment?

Comment: Oh I got that. Thank you!